# Azure Data Factory Getting error AccessToOnPremFileSystemDenied when trying to reach the self hosted IR disk

Tags: azure-data-factory

I had been using the F: of my self hosted IR in my ADF pipelines when all of a sudden I started getting an error:

Error code
AccessToOnPremFileSystemDenied
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
ErrorCode=AccessToOnPremFileSystemDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Access to 'F:' is not allowed.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common

This is pretty bad of Microsoft to change stuff on the fly.

Found this link here but nothing on stack overflow so I thought I would put something here to help others.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-file-system

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I found out that MS introduced this as a safety feature and these were the steps to disable it:

1. Log on to the Machine where the IR is hosted as an admin.
2. Run CMD as an admin.
3. Run cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Integration Runtime\5.0\Shared
4. Run dmgcmd -DisableLocalFolderPathValidation